# Example of sets $A_n \ n \in \mathbb{N}$ which are finite, but union $\cup A_n$ infinte.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I wonder if anyone can provide an example of sets $ A_n \ n \in \mathbb{N}$ where $\# A_n < \infty$ but when taking the union over $n$ $\# (\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n) = \infty$. Other than $A_n = \{n\}$

Comment: This will make it: $A_n=\{n\}$.

Comment: How about $A_n = \{7,n\}$

Comment: @Olba what is it that you're trying to do with your sets? Why isn't $A_n = \{n\}$ good enough?

Comment: It is good enough, I just wanted to know some not so trivial examples. @Omnomnomnom

Answer (score 1):

One possible example is the following:

$$A_n = \{0,1..,n\}$$

Then you have $\# A_n =n+1$, While the union over n is all the natural numbers which have infinite cardinality